# asp.net page not responding after 30 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a asp.net web page in which the button click event process runs for 35 minutes and in the front end I am using ajax and showing a progress bar image. If the process (button click event) completes in less than 30 minutes then page reloads successfully, else "in progress" image keeps showing even after the process is completed,  until the time of `AsyncPostBackTimeout` (which is set to 60 minutes) and shows server time out issue after 60 minutes.
Please let me know if there is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: What exactly is it doing for 35 minutes? I would expect that an ASP.NET event handler is not the appropriate place to execute long-running code like that.

Comment: You're doing your server-side code wrong. No web request should remain pending for thirty-five minutes. Split your work into several chunks, or use [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or similar.

Comment: your process is taking 30 minutes in itself is wrong. Do you think user will wait this long on your page?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your code, I can't tell you what's going wrong. However, I can recommend a couple of options:

- Break the task out in to multiple steps (instead of one long chained task). it may be a little more work for the user, but at least they're not left hanging on a page for a half hour+ (ouch!).
- Use a profiler to see what's actually taking so long and see if you can't optimize the code to cut down on the process. For example, if it's a database call it may make sense to make a stored procedure instead of multiple select/updates (with data doing back and forth)--keep the processing on the machine until the final result is needed.
- For long tasks, it may make sense to break the process out in to a service or separate entity (and just have the service report back progress). For example [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a great way to have a dedicated service running and pass tasks off to it when needed. Just keep in mind, this now creates another layer which is one more place to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

If a process takes 30 minutes, it could tomorrow take 60 minutes or more just because your servers will be busy doing other things. The approach is then fundamentally wrong.

My advice would be to put such long tasks to another layer, a system service. The service runs, picks tasks from a queue, executes one by one. The front layer just peeks every few seconds/minutes to see if the operation is complete. Or even better, users do not wait, they do other things and eventually somehow they are informed that the long-running task is complete.